# Passing JSON string in the URL parameters using Spring & Robospice

Tags: android, json, rest, robospice

I am writing a rest client application and the way the server has been set up (beyond my control) is to perform specific filters the query string has a raw json attached as follows:

http://www.someurl.com/api/user?filter=[{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"value3"}]

Currently I am using Robospice/Spring to handle the network requests and for regular queries (i.e. no json paramters) it works pretty well. However, whenever I try and process a GET request with the above described url, I keep receiving 500 server error. I tried the same request using [This android-async-library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), which seems to be able to handle the parameters a little better (200 OK etc). This has lead me to believe the issue is with the way the URL is formed/parsed.

My question is can Spring handle URLs of this format? or if anyone knows the best way to handle/encode it that will be usable for spring?

Answer (score 0):

Yes possibly your url should be encoded especially when you post json in parameters(because of  ", :, }, ' notations)
use this for creating your url

```
String url = Uri.parse("http://youradres.com")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("filter", "[{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\",\"field3\":\"value3\"}]")
                .build().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just tried it and no luck, still getting similar behaviour.

Comment: Weird that spring seems to have issues with this (or i'm going about it the wrong way)

Comment: print your url string to log. Copy and paste to a browser, see the result. or mybe your problem comes from the service that you use7

Comment: "{'field1':'value1','field2':'value2','field3':'value3'}]" also you should try that way maybe your json string  encoded in a weird way

Comment: This is strange; I took the outputted URL string from the logcat & manually pasted in the browser works. And as I mentioned, the URL works fine with another library I tested, so I am wondering if anyone else has experience with these type of queries using robospice/spring?

@ismail Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried the single quotes with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not a good idea. I would pass those values like this:

```
http://www.someurl.com/api/user?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3
```

And manage those values on your controller. I think it is more rest-ish. However, going straight to your question. I think the problem is you need to "encode" your URL before you send those values. And then decode it back in your server.

I can not give you code because I don't use Java but this might help you to get on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not too familiar with spring framework outside of android (ie the controller paradigm etc) - it seems not to require it. In terms of the encoding side, I have used the android/java inbuilt URI builder which automatically encodes the url but to no success. But again, another library managed to handle it fine, so it's interesting to see if it's a spring issue or something else going on.